# Toggle checkbox when click on parent div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bootstrap-4

I'm stuck with the jquery part where I need to toggle checkbox("#abc" & "#aac") whenever I click on jumbotron div box("#ab & #aa"). Following is the code:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  $("#ab").on('click', function(){
    $("#abc").prop('checked', true);
  });
  $("#aa").click(function(){
    $("#aac").prop('checked', true);
  });

});
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container-fluid mt-4">
  <h3 class="mb1">
    <i class="fa fa-check-square"></i> Select the extras you'd like us to arrange...
  </h3>
  <div class="row jumbotron style-04 m-2 py-2 mt-4" id="ab" style="cursor:pointer;">
    <div class="col-11 pt-3">
      <p class="fs-18"><i class="fa fa-building fa-fw"></i>Accommodation before your trip</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-1 pt-3 text-right">
      <input type="checkbox" class="accommodationOption" name="abc" id="abc">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row jumbotron style-04 m-2 py-2 mt-4" id="aa" style="cursor:pointer;">
    <div class="col-11 pt-3">
      <p class="fs-18"><i class="fa fa-building fa-fw"></i> Accommodation after your trip</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-1 pt-3 text-right">
      <input type="checkbox" class="accommodationOption" name="aac" id="aac">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To toggle the `checked` state you can provide a function to `prop()` which accepts the current state as an argument. You can then `return` the inverse of this boolean value to toggle it:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#ab").on('click', function() {
    $("#abc").prop('checked', function(i, checked) {
      return !checked;
    });
  });

  $("#aa").click(function() {
    $("#aac").prop('checked', function(i, checked) {
      return !checked;
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container-fluid mt-4">
  <h3 class="mb1">
    <i class="fa fa-check-square"></i> Select the extras you'd like us to arrange...
  </h3>
  <div class="row jumbotron style-04 m-2 py-2 mt-4" id="ab" style="cursor:pointer;">
    <div class="col-11 pt-3">
      <p class="fs-18"><i class="fa fa-building fa-fw"></i>Accommodation before your trip</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-1 pt-3 text-right">
      <input type="checkbox" class="accommodationOption" name="abc" id="abc">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row jumbotron style-04 m-2 py-2 mt-4" id="aa" style="cursor:pointer;">
    <div class="col-11 pt-3">
      <p class="fs-18"><i class="fa fa-building fa-fw"></i> Accommodation after your trip</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-1 pt-3 text-right">
      <input type="checkbox" class="accommodationOption" name="aac" id="aac">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

That being said, you can make the logic more simple and extensible by using common classes on `#ab` and `#aa` then using DOM traversal to find the related checkbox:

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $(".check-toggle").on('click', function() {
    $(this).find(':checkbox').prop('checked', function(i, checked) {
      return !checked;
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.check-toggle {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container-fluid mt-4">
  <h3 class="mb1">
    <i class="fa fa-check-square"></i> Select the extras you'd like us to arrange...
  </h3>
  <div class="row jumbotron style-04 m-2 py-2 mt-4 check-toggle">
    <div class="col-11 pt-3">
      <p class="fs-18"><i class="fa fa-building fa-fw"></i>Accommodation before your trip</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-1 pt-3 text-right">
      <input type="checkbox" class="accommodationOption" name="abc" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row jumbotron style-04 m-2 py-2 mt-4 check-toggle">
    <div class="col-11 pt-3">
      <p class="fs-18"><i class="fa fa-building fa-fw"></i> Accommodation after your trip</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-1 pt-3 text-right">
      <input type="checkbox" class="accommodationOption" name="aac" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you don't care about supporting IE then it can be made simpler still:

```
$(this).find(':checkbox').prop('checked', (i, checked) => !checked);
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to fix this and it's working fine

Basically you were missing one condition.
have a look to code snippet and you will understand.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  $("#ab").on('click', function(){
    if($('#abc').prop("checked") == true){
   $("#abc").prop('checked', false)
 }
    else{
    $("#abc").prop('checked', true);
    }
    
  });
  $("#aa").click(function(){
      if($('#aac').prop("checked") == true){
        $("#aac").prop('checked', false);
      }
    else{
        $("#aac").prop('checked', true);
    }
  });

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container-fluid mt-4">
  <h3 class="mb1">
    <i class="fa fa-check-square"></i> Select the extras you'd like us to arrange...
  </h3>
  <div class="row jumbotron style-04 m-2 py-2 mt-4" id="ab" style="cursor:pointer;">
    <div class="col-11 pt-3">
      <p class="fs-18"><i class="fa fa-building fa-fw"></i>Accommodation before your trip</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-1 pt-3 text-right">
      <input type="checkbox" class="accommodationOption" name="abc" id="abc">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row jumbotron style-04 m-2 py-2 mt-4" id="aa" style="cursor:pointer;">
    <div class="col-11 pt-3">
      <p class="fs-18"><i class="fa fa-building fa-fw"></i> Accommodation after your trip</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-1 pt-3 text-right">
      <input type="checkbox" class="accommodationOption" name="aac" id="aac">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
<script>
</script>
</html>
```